# How to change ImageBrush dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is some code that does not work:

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox />
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="image_background" Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" />
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

**C#:** (It does not work to dynamically change image.)

```
image_background.ImageSource = null;
image_background.ImageSource = CreateBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)); // Black Color
```

Is not changing the image, any solution?

Here is code that works fine.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // work fine
   image_background.ImageSource = CreateBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));
}
```

UPDATE:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(() => image_background.ImageSource = CreateBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0))));
```

Comment: Running on a background thread?

Comment: @kennyzx yes,,,

Comment: @kennyzx I have tried and it has not resolved.

Comment: Marshal your code to the UI thread using Dispatcher.Invoke, then the code should be working. You cannot access the ImageBrush from a background thread.

Comment: I was wrong in giving that freezable advice.

Comment: @kennyzx, Please see my post, I put a code there and nothing happens. The old image remains.